# Mock API to give response based on request URL's dynamic part

Tags: automated-tests, httprequest, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I would like to mock API calls so that 
request to 
`http://localhost:8080/api/test/<yyyy-mm-dd>` 
gives a response: 
`{date: <yyyy-mm-dd>, data: 'my cool data'}`
where `<yyyy-mm-dd>` is not fixed (This request is made 7 times for last 7 days)

How can I create a mock for this in TestCafé? Note that response data depends on the request URL.

Comment: Why not use one of online mocking tool with dynamic response support? Like https://mockservice.io

Comment: You can use online tool to mock apis. Like: https://themockapis.in/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place `index.html` and `index.js` files in the same folder. Then run `testcafe chrome test.js` command in your terminal.

*index.html*

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Page</h1>
        <button id="sendRequestBtn">Send request</button>
        <code id='response'></code>
        <script>
            var sendRequestBtn = document.getElementById('sendRequestBtn');
            var responseData   = document.getElementById('response');

            sendRequestBtn.addEventListener('click', function (){
                fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/test/2019-07-12')
                    .then(response => {
                         return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(json => {
                         responseData.textContent = JSON.stringify(json, null, 4);
                    })
                    .catch(e => console.error(e));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*test.js*

```js
import { RequestMock } from 'testcafe';

const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(/http:\/\/localhost:8080\/api\/test\/.*/)
    .respond((req, res) => {
        res.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = '*'; // It's necessary because TestCafe load the page via file protocol in this example.

        const dateUrlPart = req.path.replace('/api/test/', '');

        res.setBody({
            date: dateUrlPart, 
            data: 'my cool data'
        });
    });

fixture `Fixture`
    .page('./index.html')
    .requestHooks(mock);

test('test', async t => {
    await t.click('#sendRequestBtn').wait(1000);
});
```